# system error is null from GradesManagementService

Tags: desire2learn

In case of a system error from the GradesManagementService, the returned response object is null, but the response header includes the diagnostic information. What class do I use to get this information?

Here is my code:

```
GradesManagementServiceV10 port = service.getGradesManagementServiceV10(); 
GetGradeValuesByOrgUnitRequest r = new GetGradeValuesByOrgUnitRequest(); GetGradeValuesByOrgUnitResponse resp = new GetGradeValuesByOrgUnitResponse(); WSBindingProvider bp = (WSBindingProvider)port; bp.setOutboundHeaders( Headers.create(formatSOAPHeader())); ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, getUrl()); 
resp = port.getGradeValuesByOrgUnit(r); // the response is null. <------  How do I see what the error is?
```

Answer (score 1):

In your service object (in the above code snippet that would be `port`, the object of the Web service proxy class `GradesManagementServiceV10`), `ResponseHeader` property would contain such information (this property's type is `ResponseHeaderInfo`).

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing new development with Desire2Learn I would also suggest that you look at the Valence REST/JSON API. New features and new API calls are going to show up in that system http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/ (it is always deployed, the docs are open, etc.)